# Find the value of a 2D arrays neighbors?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, processing

I have a 2d array that generates terrain using perlin noise, and then places a (3D) block at a specific height - Before you click away, all I need help with is the 2D array that generates the "height-map". I am trying to figure out whether or not the block next to it is at the same elevation (if it is "neighboring" or not)  by checking the values directly up, down, left, and right in the 2D array. If they are equal, then they are at the same elevation, and therefore "neighbors". if  the problem that I am running into is that the check is always returning true for all the neighbors, even if the block has no neighbors.

A small example of the perlin noise height map

```
151514141312121111
151414131313121211
141414131312121211
141313131312121211
131313121212121111
131312121212111111
121212121111111111
111111111110101111
111111111010101111
111111111010101010
111111111010101010
101011101010101010
101010101099109999
991010109999988889
999109999888888999
```

and here is the checking code, you will have to see the entire file, linked below for context

```java
      if (terrain[x][leftColumn] == terrain[x][z]) {
        neighbors[2] = true; // left side
      }
      if (terrain[x][rightColumn] == terrain[x][z]) {
        neighbors[3] = true; //right side
      }
      if (terrain[belowRow][z] == terrain[x][z]) {
        neighbors[4] = true; // front side (below)
      }
      if (terrain[aboveRow][z] == terrain[x][z]) {
        neighbors[5] = true; // back side (above)
      }
```

Pastebin: https://www.pastiebin.com/5d5c5416391ec 
any help is appreciated, Asher

Comment: You're reusing the same neighbors array for all the iteration of the loop, and you never set any of its elements to false. So, once a neighbor becomes tru for one cell, it's true for all the remaining cells. Learn about **local** variables. Reduce the scope of your variables as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Move this static variable initialization

```
boolean[] neighbors = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false};
```

inside the inner loop, where you check each block's neighbors, to instantiate a new neighbors array for each individual block. Right now neighbors is a static variable. You never reset the values on the neighbors array so it remains true after each iteration.

edit:

Also

```
  if (belowRow > 1) { 
    belowRowExists = false;
    belowRow = 0;
  } 
  if (rightColumn > - 1) { 
    rightColumnExists = false;
    rightColumn = 0;
  }
```

is wrong, you want to check if the column or row is out of bounds right? Then you want to see if they are >= chunkSize.

Comment: it kind of works, however some of the blocks don't sense sense their neighbors,but that may be another problem with my code, im not sure

Comment: editted the answer, I believe that should solve the problem

Comment: that improves it, but it is still not sensing its neighbors correctly